# проблема кириллицей windows-1251 при работе с requests в python3 - кодировка типа ^%^CF^%^F0^%^E5^%^EA^%^F0^%^E0^%^F1

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, cp1251

код вида

```
response = requests.post('http://.ru/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
response.encoding = 'cp1251'
print(response.text)
```

выводит в консоль часть текста на кириллице, а часть в непонятной кодировке типа

> ^%^CF^%^F0^%^E5^%^EA^%^F0^%^E0^%^F1

при том, что в браузере текст выглядит одинаково
может кто-то сталкивался? из чего декодировать?

Comment: разобрался, что '^' тут просто лишний, если их удалить, получится url_encoded cp1251, пытаюсь разобраться, как переводить в utf

Comment: правильное решение - 
syn = s.get_text(strip=True)
syn = syn.replace('^','')
print(urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(syn).decode('cp1251'))

Comment: Так ли нужно принудительно ставить кодировку? Что выводит `print(response.content)` там где кириллица? И что возвращается в `print(response.headers.get('Content-Type'))` -- в заголовке должно быть указание о используемой кодировке

Answer (score 0):

правильное решение, если в переменой s нужный тег -

```
syn = s.get_text(strip=True) 
syn = syn.replace('^','') 
print(urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(syn).decode('cp1251'))
```

варианты с unquote и unquote_plus не работают

Comment: `s` это переменная-тег `bs4`?